# My app crashes report from google play cosole

Tags: android, google-play-console

I new to android development.I have developed an app and posted it to google play but recently i have found the crashes report as many crashes occurs at specific part of the code as below. I cannot figure it out.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity 
 (ActivityThread.java:2643)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity 
 (ActivityThread.java:2709)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000 (ActivityThread.java:196)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage 
 (ActivityThread.java:1534)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:111)
 at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:207)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5867)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run 
 (ZygoteInit.java:1026)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:887)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
 at local.app.user.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate 
 (MainActivity.java:154)
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6285)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate   ( 
 Instrumentation.java:1119)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity 
 (ActivityThread.java:2596)
```

Comment: (MainActivity.java:154) what is this line 154

Comment: More precise there's a null object there =) That's causing the crash!

Comment: post your java code

Comment: Can you please give your java code of MainActivity Class. Because this is null pointer exception. this exception is thrown when an application attempts to use an object reference that has the null value. 
For example  Object obj = null;

obj.toString();  // This statement will throw a NullPointerException